# How to add additional parameters on a form, submitting it with GET method

Tags: html

I have this form :

```
<form method='GET' name='search' action='index.php?explore=search'> 
    <input type="hidden" name="searchType" value="all" />
    <input class="inputSearchSmall" name="search">
</form>
<a href="javascript:document.search.submit()"><img src="img/button_search.png" class="buttonSearch" /></a>
```

and I'd like to add parameters on the query string, after the action link. So, the result must be:

```
http://localhost:8080/website/index.php?explore=search&searchType=all&search=example
```

not :

```
http://localhost:8080/website/index.php?searchType=all&search=example
```

what's the best way to do this? Adding a hidden param like :

```
<input type="hidden" name="explore" value="search" />
```

Or can I concatenate the parameters to the action script in some way?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Adding them via a hidden param like you've suggested is the best way to go. It's more maintainable than adding to the form's action attribute value, and will do exactly what your asking. Just make sure you put it within the form tags.

Answer (score 2):

Either way will work - hidden input elements *or* adding parameters to the `action` attribute of the `form` element.

There really isn't a "preferred" way - do what makes most sense to you, though if you want to add, delete and change parameters using hidden input elements will be easier to work with.

Comment: hi, how can we add parameter through action attribute?

Comment: @GMsoF - On the URL `action="somepage.someext?param1=a&param2=b"`.

Comment: hi thank your quick reply. What if the parameter is dependent on the other input? I cannot use 'hidden' because I either want the new parameter to be on or off.

Comment: @GMsoF - You _can_ use hidden inputs. But you also need to use JavaScript. How you use it is up to you - using `action`, `input type="hidden"` or directly on the URL.